# Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") always returns 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added main user object for a 3d shooter, attached camera for it and trying to catch mouse moving in the code of the script, attached to the player game object. But can not use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`, `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")`, because they always zero. Why? What I did wrong? `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` and `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` for keys work good.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

  public enum RotationAxes {
    MouseXAndY = 0,
    MouseX = 1,
    MouseY = 2
  }

  public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
  public float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
  public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
  public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
  public float maximumVert = 45.0f;
  private float _rotationX = 0;

  void Start() {
    Rigidbody body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if (body != null)
      body.freezeRotation = true;
  }

  void Update() {
    Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
    Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX) {
      transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0);
    } else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY) {
      _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
      _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
      float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
      transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    } else {
      _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
      _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
      float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor;
      float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;
    }
```

I expect the output of `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"`) to be from -1 to 1, but the actual output is 0. I see it in `Debug.Log`.

Comment: Have you read the [Input.GetAxis documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)?  Are Mouse X/Y valid inputs and axes?

Comment: What version of unity are you on? Is Mouse X and Y valid in the version you have? as for example the 2 debugs work fine in 2019.1.6

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Input settings with the `Mouse X` and the `Mouse Y` axes expanded so we can see the settings.

Comment: I'l try to install now 2019.1.6. I use unity on Windows in Virtualbox on Centos. I use 2019.3.0a4 version.

Answer (score 2):

Check your unity input settings, `Mouse X` and `Mouse Y` Should be defined as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I use free version of unity. Didn't see right menu in my version - only words under Mouse X and Mouse Y.

Comment: @アーティストアーティスト Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: O, sorry, it was just bad stretching of subwindow. My settings exactly as yours.

Comment: Maybe I need some components which I don't have?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem I experienced by clearing PlayerPrefs;

Go to `Editor Window Menus > "Edit" > "Clear All PlayerPrefs"`

It should solve the issue.